# Node JS NPM install error

Tags: node.js, npm

I keep getting errors after errors while trying to get a package with NPM.
I have solved most of them but now i'm getting this :

```
rs\kevin\Desktop\adwordsapi\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib' [C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\adwordsa
pi\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib
\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node
_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\adwordsapi\node_modules\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\adwordsapi\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\adwordsapi\package.json'
npm WARN adwordsapi No description
npm WARN adwordsapi No repository field.
npm WARN adwordsapi No README data
npm WARN adwordsapi No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ursa@0.9.4 (node_modules\ursa):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

I have no idea what's going on and hoped some of you could help

Comment: it clearly says that it is not able to find your `package.json` file. Move to the directory containing you `package,json` and then run `npm install`

Comment: Seems like the "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib" file for compilation of the native ursa module is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link error in you error output, it seems that you are missing some required dependencies to compile the native module.

Installing the `ursa` node module on Windows requires some extra preparation steps. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ursa#windows-install for further documentation.

Hope this helps.